# How to use Google font in wordpress?

Tags: html, css, wordpress, fonts, google-font-api

My custom css has the following code

```
h1 a  { 
  font-family:'Droid Sans Mono''Share Tech Mono''Ropa Sans', sans-serif;
'Poiret One''Cutive Mono''Helvetica Neue''Arial'; !important;
}
```

this is at the top of my custom css:

```
@import url (http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto|Droid+Sans+Mono|Share+Tech+Mono|Ropa+Sans|Cutive+Mono|Poiret+One|Lato:100,600,900) ;
```

and my in page code is:

```
<h1 style="font-size: 25px; font-weight: bold; color: #ffffff; hover font-family:'Droid Sans Mono''Share Tech Mono''Ropa Sans', sans-serif;"><a href="http://www.xxx.com/?page_id=4348"></h1>
```

But the none of the fonts seem to be loading. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: that's A LOT of fonts for just one website. this will slow it down a lot.

Comment: Thanks. will only use 2 now

Answer (score 1):

You're loading the CSS in your custom CSS, which is good, but you're not calling it properly.

You have this:

```
h1 a  { 
  font-family:'Droid Sans Mono''Share Tech Mono''Ropa Sans', sans-serif;
  'Poiret One''Cutive Mono''Helvetica Neue''Arial'; !important;
}
```

Not only is that code wrong, it's scary.

This is what it should be like:

```
h1 a  { 
  font-family: 'Droid Sans Mono', 'Share Tech Mono', 'Ropa Sans', sans-serif, 'Poiret One', 'Cutive Mono', 'Helvetica Neue', 'Arial' !important;
}
```

Each new font call should be seperated with a `,` and the `!important` goes before the `;` and the style will always only have one `;` right at the **very end** of the css style rule.

Also just for the record, there is no good reason you need to include that amount of fonts, and if `Droid Sans Mono` and `Share Tech Mono` and even `Ropa Sans` don't load, anything after `sans-serif` won't load as `sans-serif` will be the font of choice as it's a default choice and should only really be used as a last resort/fallback (if you have other fonts you want to take precedence, that is).

If they do load, then you're only going to ever be using `Droid Sans Mono` and then it's a waste calling all the other fonts.

Make sure you're actually using all of those fonts, as it could essentially slow down the website load time drastically.

**Side note:**

Please try and refrain from using inline css (css that is put in using the `style` in a html attribute). However, if you must do it, you need to fix your `h1` tag also:

```
<h1 style="font-size: 25px; font-weight: bold; color: #ffffff; font-family:'Droid Sans Mono', 'Share Tech Mono', 'Ropa Sans', sans-serif;"><a href="http://www.xxx.com/?page_id=4348"></h1>
```

Don't just include the word `hover` in there because it will break your CSS and anything after has a high chance of not running. Again, separate each instance of font with a `,` and have only a `;` after each new css style rule.

You don't need both inline css and a css file styling two identical attributes, just use the `.css` file.

Please make sure that you have `url(` and not `url (`. Although it is a simple  (space), it is a function and will not work if the `(` is not directly after `url`.

Comment: also with this syntax the h1 tag will be always loaded with the 'Droid Sans Mono' font-family. i can't see why you are giving all these font-families to the same h1 tag

Comment: It must be something else then, because with the code you've given us, this is what's wrong. @user3560300

Comment: Also make sure you're actually calling the `.css` file if it's a custom one @user3560300

Comment: the default css is always called. My in page is now: <h1 style="font-size: 25px; font-weight: bold; color: #666666;><a href="http://www.example.com/?page_id=4348">services</a></h1> And my custom CSS includes @import url (http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Droid+Sans+Mono) ;h1 a  {   font-family: 'Droid Sans Mono'}  but still nothing

Comment: You haven't got a closing `"` after `color:#666666` in the `h1` tag. @user3560300

Comment: Also it should be `url(` not `url (` (no space!) @user3560300

Comment: Still not loading. Should I be loading the font in page too?

Comment: If it's in the custom css and being already called, then it should be ok. @user3560300

Comment: Started from scratch and I think I identified the problem. When I inspect the element h1 is definitely calling droid sans mono but i think its just not being loaded. I dont want to mess with the core code so i cant use <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Droid+Sans+Mono' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>. I really need to fix this

Comment: so it turns out @import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Droid+Sans+Mono); only works in the theme css and not when added to the custom css...even though I know its being called on.

Comment: Odd, have you got it working now though? @user3560300

Comment: No I haven't. Was thinking about updating the css every time a new theme is installed...but a work around would be preferred.

Comment: Stick with one theme? ;) @user3560300

Answer (score 0):

you're not loading the font anywhere. i suggest you install and use this plugin: http://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-google-fonts/

you'll choose the font you want on your website and you will be able to use it.
hope this helps

Comment: sorry updated original post. the font are being loaded

Comment: still, it doesn't seem you are an expert of html/css. consider using that plugin, it's very simple to configure and use (i use it on my blog and it took me like 10seconds to have it up and running)

Comment: Definitely not an expert but i like learning the hard way so i can be in the future. Would like to know why somethings not working so i know in the future.

Comment: try using the standard code in the <head> instead: <link href='your fonts' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>

Comment: Custom pages in wordpress don't have <head> and I don't want to mess with the theme files.

Comment: that's why you should use the plugin ;) anyway, it's probably not working because the @import goes in the first line of the theme's css file.